# Exporting Spring Boot application as JAR file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, rest, maven

I'm using the Spring STS in Eclipse to create a simple web-based spring boot project. I can run it fine in Eclipse, but when I try to export it as a JAR file I get:

```
rg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

My `public static void main`is located in `Application.java`, with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

I've double checked all the Maven dependencies a hundred times.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does running `mvn package` give you a working jar?

Comment: @chrylis I can't figure out how to run `mvn` commands, bash doesn't find it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most likely, you're using *the built-in Eclipse exporter* to generate your jar, which only includes the target files actually produced in that project. In order to have a "fat" (standalone executable) jar, you need to use the Spring Boot Maven or Gradle plugin to "repackage" the jar.

First, make sure that [you have the `repackage` goal included in your build setup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html), then use the Maven `package` target. The simplest way to do this is to run `mvn package` from the command line (you may need to install the Maven CLI package for your OS); you can also right-click the POM in Eclipse and "Run As" to execute specific Maven operations from within Eclipse.

Comment: Fantastic!! The very last part of your answer did the trick for me, I didn't realise I had to "run" the pom.xml with Maven. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @ViggoLundén Happy to help. I do recommend getting familiar with running Maven from the CLI (just like Git), because it's the "official" approach used by CI tools and the like (it provides the so-called "one-step build"), and M2Eclipse has a few subtle bugs, mostly relating to the classpath, that can bite you if you don't do your pre-push tests from the CLI.

Answer (score 14):

It is a single line command, on window 7/10 machine, with command prompt to your project folder (Inside your project workspace). I do not do with Eclipse IDE POM maven goals, but you can do with maven goal there also. ON window machine I prefer cmd.exe for exporting and running.

```
mvnw clean package
```

on unix kernel based

```
./mvnw clean package
```

You have to go inside workspace and than to the project root folder. You will see a maven wrapper mvnw, with that you don't need to have maven installed and .mvn folder at the same level provides necessary jar for that.
For a project

```
D:\workspace\Zuteller Workspace\zusteller>mvnw clean package
```

it will create `zusteller-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the **target** folder at the same level.

```
D:\workspace\Zuteller Workspace\zusteller>java -jar target\zusteller-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You can run self-contained application(embedded Tomcat) and access at localhost:8080/your project