# spring boot; using java -jar; not executing but no error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was trying to execute spring boot; it works fine with mvn spring-boot:run. But when i try to package it as jar (I moved dependencies to lib, and binary to bin and resources to resources folder)
command was java -cp lib/*;bin/*;resource/* com.sample.SampleBoot
(SampleBoot's jar is available in bin)
This starts and print the line mentioned in main, but while calling application.run(args) [application is instance of SpringApplication), it is coming back with out starting the server.
It is not throwing any error or exception as well. So it is tough to debug.
Any help or advise?

Comment: did you run mvn spring-boot:repackage to create runnable jar from maven?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the jar like this

```
mvn package spring-boot:repackage
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Creating a simple runnable jar file won't include the libraries in pom.xml.

If you're using eclipse, run this maven command below to create a runnable jar file in Spring Boot to include all libraries:

```
clean package
```

Reference to almost same question [Exporting Spring Boot application as JAR file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016040/exporting-spring-boot-application-as-jar-file-in-eclipse)