# How to export jar file of Spring Boot Maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have one Maven project, internally reading file from project resource folder and processing. I just want to run it from command screen as `java -jar Sample.jar`, but I'm not able to do it.
How to export jar including file also inside?

I have the required plugins in the pom.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
      </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is this a Spring boot project as you have written in the head line? If yes you should use the spring-boot-maven-plugin ....

Comment: This is not my full `pom.xml` . I use that plugin too. The code which i shared i checked from another questions. But does not work for me

Comment: @Mrkrky have you tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217853/8035260)